# Erro query pdo (Ordenar por count)

Tags: sql, pdo, query

Estou tentando fazer um ranking baseado na quantidade de moedas de cada um. Na ordem decrescente.
Utilizei essa query no pdo:

```
$ranking = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE banido='false' GROUP BY usuario ORDER BY count(moedas) DESC LIMIT 3");
```

Código completo:

```
<?php
                                $ranking = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE banido='false' GROUP BY usuario ORDER BY count(moedas) DESC LIMIT 3");
                                $i = 1;
                                while($ver = $ranking->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                                    if($i == 1){
                                        $class = 'gold';
                                    }
                                    else if($i == 2){
                                        $class = 'silver';
                                    }
                                    else if($i == 3){
                                        $class = 'bronze';
                                    }
                            ?>
                            <div class="registry big <?php echo $class; ?>">
                                <div class="rBox"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<a href="#"><?php echo $ver['usuario']; ?></a></div>
                                <div class="base">
                                    <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?&user=<?php echo $ver['usuario']; ?>&action=std&direction=3&head_direction=3&img_format=png&gesture=std&headonly=0&size=b')"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="comments"><i class="fa fa-tint" aria-hidden="true"></i><br><?php echo $ver['moedas']; ?></div>
                            </div>
                            <?php $i++; } ?>
```

Porém, não estou conseguindo encontrar o erro. O primeiro lugar está correto, porém no segundo lugar aparece um usuário aleatório com 0 de moedas, e o 3º com suas moedas devidas, porem era pra estar no 2º lugar.

Comment: Não seria `ORDER BY moedas DESC` simplesmente?

Comment: Qual seu SGDB ?

Comment: Explique melhor a estrutura da tabela, e por que você precisou agrupar os resultados.

Comment: Puts, você estava certo @bfavaretto. Grande vacilo dei, me confundi. ORDER BY moedas DESC Resolveu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente adicionar um alias

```
SELECT *, COUNT(moedas) AS money
FROM usuarios
WHERE banido='false' GROUP BY usuario
ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: Acabou não exibindo nada.

Comment: Editei, pode tentar novamente

Comment: Continuou com o problema da ordem.

Comment: Print do problema: http://prntscr.com/fppzku